# C.D.F. expression $P(X^2-X-1>0)$ for standard normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

> Let $X$ be a random variable with a normal distribution such that $E(X) =
> µ$ and $Var(X) = \sigma^2$. Suppose that $μ=0$ and that $\sigma=1$, then my textbook posits the question to find $$P(X^2-X-1>0)$$

***Thoughts:***
Usually with these types of problems I attempt to rewrite the left-hand side of the inequality for $Z= \frac {x -μ}{\sigma}$ but that doesn't seem to apply here.

My other thoughts is that this is equivalent to the integral 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac  {e^{\frac {-(x^2-x-1)^2}{2}}}{\sqrt {2\pi}} dx$$ but I am not sure how this helps. Any tips or insights appreciated.

Comment: I am really curious to know how you came to the notion that $$P(X^2-X-1>0)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac  {e^{-(x^2-x-1)^2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}} dx\ ?$$ Adding a missing $\frac12$ in the exponential, it looks like you think that on should have $$P(g(X)>0)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac  {e^{-g(x)^2/2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}} dx$$ for every function $g$, that is, probably that, for every real number $u$, $$P(g(X)>u)=\int_u^\infty f_X(g(x))dx$$ for every function $g$ and every random variable $X$ of PDF $f_X$? Of course, none of this holds but, once again, I would love to understand where it comes from...

Comment: Your intuition is right, that is how I thought about it. Why does it not hold? This is my first probability class so I am an outright beginner.

Comment: @JamesDickens It is not quite so simple. The cleanest way I know to explain it is to pass through the CDF: to calculate the CDF of $Y=g(X)$, call it $F_Y(y)$, you need to identify the set $\{ x : g(x) \leq y \}$ and compute its probability. Then to get the pdf of $Y$ (if it exists) you can differentiate that CDF. The situation is fairly simple when $g$ is monotone, but it can be quite complicated in general. For example, in your problem here, $g(x)=x^2-x-1$ is not monotone, which is why the set $\{ x : x^2-x-1>0 \}$ is not just an interval but rather a union of two intervals.

Comment: Well, in full generality, the *definitions* yield $$P(g(X)>u)=\int_Df_X(x)dx$$ where $$D=\{x\mid g(x)>u\}$$ which does not even involve $f_X\circ g$, right?

Comment: Well, in the monotone case it does *involve* $f_X \circ g$ but even in that case it is not so simple as all that.

Comment: @Ian No, even in this case, it would involve $f_X\circ g^{-1}$, not $f\circ g$. (Please use @ next time, thanks in advance.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=x^2-x-1$ has distinct real roots $r_1,r_2$ (which you can explicitly calculate). For clarity assume $r_1<r_2$. It factors to $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$. Consequently "$X^2-X-1>0$" is equivalent to "$X-r_1<0$ or $X-r_2>0$". Since these events are disjoint you can compute their probabilities and add them up.